# word for assuming something larger from a small sample size

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there a word for making an assumption of something larger from a small external part (possibly erroneously)?

For example:

> judging a person's entire moral character by one of his crimes.

Comment: Hi @Eliana, Have you researched this at all yourself? If so, please add that information, including citations. Ideally, questions on English Language & Usage will reflect some research effort by the requester. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[***extrapolate***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/extrapolate)

> When you *extrapolate*, you use specific details to make a general conclusion. For example, if you travel to Canada and encounter only friendly, kind natives, you might extrapolate that all Canadians are friendly.

*(vocabulary.com)*

Comment: I think _generalize_ (a synonym listed on the page you linked to) would work better than _extrapolate_.

Comment: @J.R. - For mathematicians, and people who work with math, *extrapolate* is a strong, specific word.  It is more prone to error than *generalize*.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (I usually associate that word with data and experiments, not, say, judging a person's moral character.) That said, the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/extrapolate) page has some examples that fit quite nicely. Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

As for the part about "possibly erroneously," there's the term **hasty generalization**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization):

> **Hasty generalization** is an informal fallacy of faulty generalization by reaching an inductive generalization based on insufficient evidence—essentially making a hasty conclusion without considering all of the variables.

There's also the idiom ***jumping to conclusions***.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *judging a book by its cover*: judging the whole by some prominently visible part of the whole.

See [Don't judge a book by its cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_judge_a_book_by_its_cover) (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

It is some times called ***judging*** (yes, the same word as used in your example!).

M-W:

> **[judge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judge)**
>   *verb*
>   *judged; judging*
>
> **5** :  to form an estimate or evaluation of : *trying to judge the amount of time required*;
>   **especially** :  to form a negative opinion
>   about : *shouldn't judge him because of his accent*